# Scrapy: How to save a list from our spider class in a file when scraping

Tags: python, scrapy

I am finding list of webpage links from a start url and then finding all links by following into those pages. I am currently saving these as a list in self.links, and I want to know how to save it as csv or json file after scraping is done. My goal is to call a new function to process data on each followed pages.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    links = []
    start_urls = ["https://books.toscrape.com/"]
   
    # Define the `parse` method. This method will be called for each page that the spider crawls.

    def parse(self, response):
        to_avoid = ['tel','facebook','twitter','instagram','privacy','terms','contact','java','cookies','policies','google','mail']
        # to_allow = self.current
        le = LinkExtractor(deny=to_avoid)
        ex_links = le.extract_links(response)
        for href in ex_links:
            # print(href.url)
            url = response.urljoin(href.url)
            if self.current in url:
                self.links.append(url)
                # print(url)
                yield response.follow(url, callback = self.parse)
```

I tried using another parse_landing_page(self, response) function and yielded it in the parse() function. But didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy has this functionality built in as Feed Exports. In order to use the feature all you have to do is yield a dictionary from your parse method and then  specify where to save the contents on the command line or in the settings for your spider.

For example:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    links = []
    start_urls = ["https://books.toscrape.com/"]
    custom_settings = {
        "FEEDS": {
            "items.csv": {
                "format": "csv",
                "fields": ["link"],
            }
        }
    }
   
    # Define the `parse` method. This method will be called for each page that the spider crawls.

    def parse(self, response):
        to_avoid = ['tel','facebook','twitter','instagram','privacy','terms','contact','java','cookies','policies','google','mail']
        # to_allow = self.current
        le = LinkExtractor(deny=to_avoid)
        ex_links = le.extract_links(response)
        for href in ex_links:
            # print(href.url)
            url = response.urljoin(href.url)
            if self.current in url:
                yield {'link': url}
                yield response.follow(url, callback = self.parse)
```

Or instead of using the custom settings you could just use the `-o` option on the command line:

```
scrapy crawl myspider -o items.csv
```